# Using ControlClick coordinates on a window without any controls

Tags: autohotkey

I need to send a click to a position on a non-active window. This window does not have any clickable controls at said coordinates.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetControlDelay -1
ControlClick, x636 y189,WindowTitle,,,, NA Pos
```

Every time I run the code above, it wont click at the position I specified. It instead clicks on my current mouse position, regardless of whether or not the window is active.

Comment: Maybe that window is hidden? Try [DetectHiddenWindows, On](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DetectHiddenWindows.htm)

Comment: Tried that, same issue, it works the click, but doesnt click on the coordinate, it clicks on the mouse position,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more ideas:

Update your AHK:
https://autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe

Run your script as admin:

```
If not A_IsAdmin ;force the script to run as admin
{
    Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    ExitApp
}
```

Use [PostMessage](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) instead of [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm):

```
PostClick(636,189,"WindowTitle")

PostClick(x,y,win="A") {
    lParam := x & 0xFFFF | (y & 0xFFFF) << 16
    PostMessage, 0x201, , %lParam%, , %win% ;WM_LBUTTONDOWN 
    PostMessage, 0x202, , %lParam%, ,  %win% ;WM_LBUTTONUP 
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote even I didnt test it out, since I lost the code and didnt work on it afterwards, but it can be helpfull for others.

Answer (score 2):

Oh.  If no control in the window to click at those coordinates, then `ControlClick` is not going to work.  Use a simple `MouseClick` command instead.  If you don't have the same x y coords each time, e.g., because the window moves, you can query the window position using `WinGetPos` and then pass the coords to your `MouseClick` as variables based on that result.

```
    WinGetPos, Xp, Yp, Wi, He, WindowTitle
    MouseClick, left, %Xp% + 636, %Yp% + 189
```

Comment: but it wont work with inactive window, I need a command to click in an inactive window (like minimized or not Active)

Comment: Do you have a ClassNN to click?

Comment: @RyanWildry I've found that some legacy Java webapps such as Kronos Workforce Central don't include a clickable ClassNN. ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnj2t.png))

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. [`CoordMode`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) should not be used (unless for some other reason) as it doesn't impact the positioning of a [`ControlClick`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) -- which is always relative to the `WindowTitle` window you use.

Maybe set your [`SetTitleMatchMode`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) to `2` because you are not using the exact correct `WindowTitle` text; and in addition, if your window is like a Citrix XenApp window, you may have to deal with another criteria for identifying the target window ([see `WinTitle` in help](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)).

Also, you could try to identify and use the `ClassNN` (the classname and instance number of the control) or the name/text of the control, both of which can be determined via Window Spy.

Lastly, did you try it without the `Pos` at the end?  That is used mainly when a control class conflicts with the x y position.  You can also try it without any of the stuff after `WindowTitle` as `ControlClick, x636 y189, WindowTitle` (note the space) should work by itself if you use the correct window title or other criteria:

```
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    SetControlDelay -1
    ControlClick, x636 y189, WindowTitle,,,, NA
```

or

```
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    SetControlDelay -1
    ControlClick, x636 y189, WindowTitle
```

Comment: Already tried, both the ways you told, and every time it sends the click in the mouse position instead of the coordinates, the window its finding ok, its sendind the click to the right window, but it sends to the wrong coordinate, also, there is no controls in the window I want it to click, so it needs to be by coordinate only

Comment: See other answer for another approach.  Up voted your comment as useful because it adds new info -- that there is not actually a control at the location you wanted to click.